# Stuck message when signing onto facebook

Tags: facebook

I keep getting a screen that says (please take a look: we want to make sure you know we're moving the "who can look your timeline up by name setting)

I have to shut my IPad down to get rid of it but that is not working now, please help!

There is no X to hit to remove it any more. Please don't ask me to go into my Facebook setting and do something because I can't get past this screen to do anything.

Comment: I wonder if this is related to the new Privacy Checkup. Are you using the app or just accessing via the web browser? If the latter, I suggest using a desktop browser to at least get past that alert.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't fixed it yet, turn the rotate lock button off on your ipad. Then enter the Facebook app and rotate your ipad into the portrait view. The "ok, I understand" button will appear at the bottom of the screen.